# Enable wifi in ubuntu recovery mode

Tags: networking, wireless, grub2, recovery-mode

I have a ubuntu 16.04 laptop with grub 2.02 that I can only boot in the recovery mode, but cant use wifi to fix it. The situation is thie folowing:

- `ifconfig -a` shows me only loopback and ethernet interfaces, but wlan0 does not appear. I've tried restarting the network manager with no luck.
- `lshw -c network` shows my device(intel centrino wireless), but as "*-network UNCLAIMED"
- wifi works fine with lifecd usb

What should I do to connect to the internet using wifi or fix my broken packages another way?

Comment: You can probably pick up a "blue" ethernet cable at the dollar store and plug it in between your computer and wifi router. Hopefully it will connect automatically and then you can focus on fixing your wifi. Strangely in 3 years I've never had to use **Recovery** mode and only just booted it once a fortnight ago to see what people were talking about from time to time.

Comment: Thx, but it wont work for me since I'm travelling now

Comment: There are other ways of fixing your system. If you have a working LiveUSB, then there is no problem with that. Recovery mode is not necessary. You can always chroot from LiveUSB.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert but I do know If you have phone and usb tethering you can sometimes tether to you ubuntu installation via easytether-usb, first you have to download and then install it though which can be tricky. I am also traveling and my ubuntu installation is giving me fits, luckily I was able to navigate through it well enough via terminal to complete my assignment but I will have to go and buy a usb cord capable of data tomorrow so that I can repair my installation, even though you can do fsck without internet, if you have any kind of serious problem running dpkg with an ethernet cord is your best bet and if that does not work then try to back up your files using a live usb or cd and then reinstall your main os. you can also boot into a live mode and try to repair it from there.